# Different buttons on click opens different tab but inside the same modal

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

So, I have two different buttons for example A & B. I have one modal - inside which there are two tabs called a & b. 
I want to click A to open the a tab inside the modal and clicking B should open the b tab inside the same modal.

```js
<script>
$("#loginBtn").on('click', function () {
 $('.nav-tabs a[href="#details_{{$offer->id}}"]').tab('show');
})
$("#regBtn").on('click', function () {
 $('.nav-tabs a[href="#tnc_{{$offer->id}}"]').tab('show');               
})
</script>
```

```html
<div class="pp-offer-btn">
                        @if($offer->offer_full_description != null)
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" style="cursor:pointer" id="loginBtn" data-target="#offerDetails_{{$offer->id}}">Details</button>
                        @endif
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" style="cursor:pointer" id="regBtn" data-target="#offerDetails_{{$offer->id}}">T&C</button> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal" id="offerDetails_{{$offer->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                    &times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                                    partner name
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <!-- Nav tabs -->
                                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                                <li id="loginLi"><a href="#details_{{$offer->id}}" data-toggle="tab">Details</a></li>
                                                <li id="RegLi"><a href="#tnc_{{$offer->id}}" data-toggle="tab">T&C</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <!-- Tab panes -->
                                            <!--LOGIN TAB -->
                                            <div class="tab-content">
                                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="details_{{$offer->id}}">
                                                    <div class="modal-body" style="padding-left: 2em;">
                                                        {!! html_entity_decode($offer->offer_full_description) !!}
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="tabloginMsg"></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tnc_{{$offer->id}}">
                                                    <div class="modal-body" style="padding-left: 2em;">
                                                        {!! html_entity_decode($offer->tnc) !!}
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="tabregMsg"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I searched stack overflow for similar problems and found one but it's buggy 
https://jsfiddle.net/a5voyotu/
It serves my purpose but cutting the modal and clicking on the buttons show wrong body of the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? Hope this works ;)

```
$("#loginBtn").on('click', function () {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#Login"]').tab('show');
})
$("#regBtn").on('click', function () {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#Registration"]').tab('show');               
})
```

Comment: I tried implementing this, but both the buttons open to the first tab instead of different tabs.

Comment: Hello again, this(the updated code which you gave me) works for static items but when I am trying to put dynamic values this isn't working anymore. I have updated my code please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you put the code in .ready function that may work fine
Or call rebind onclicks when the document is ready:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#loginBtn").on('click', function () {
         $('.nav-tabs a[href="#details_{{$offer->id}}"]').tab('show');
       });
      $("#regBtn").on('click', function () {
         $('.nav-tabs a[href="#tnc_{{$offer->id}}"]').tab('show');               
      });

    });
</script>
```